# Nextflow: dynamically setting resource directives for a process

Tags: nextflow

I'm trying to test variations of CPU and memory for a specific process (`samtools sort`) to measure computational efficiency (measured only by time). To do this, I'd like to set the CPU and memory for a `Nextflow` `process` dynamically.

**Ultimate question:** How can I dynamically set CPU and memory for many instances of a single `Nextflow` process definition?

## Attempt 1

The most obvious solution was to submit distinct `Nextflow` workflows for each combination of CPU and memory by specifying the CPU and memory on the command line (i.e., when calling `nextflow run ...`), where my `Nextflow` workflow has global parameters `params.samtools_total_threads` and `params.samtools_mem_per_thread`.

This didn't work perfectly because there appeared to be 'collisions' between parent `Nextflow` instances trying to lock the history file. I got the following error:

```
Can't lock file: /path/to/project/.nextflow/history -- Nextflow needs to run in a file system that supports file locks
```

I could try delaying submissions, but I suspect that will still result in collisions.

Here's the `SLURM` script that I'm using:

```
TOTAL_THREADS=$1
MEM_PER_THREAD=$2

nextflow run 02-SAMTOOLS_SORT.nf \
    -with-report "reports/report.${TOTAL_THREADS}_threads.${MEM_PER_THREAD}_GB_per_thread.html" \
    -with-trace "traces/trace.${TOTAL_THREADS}_threads.${MEM_PER_THREAD}_GB_per_thread.txt" \
    --samtools_total_threads $TOTAL_THREADS \
    --samtools_mem_per_thread $MEM_PER_THREAD
```

My workflow had the following global parameters:

```
/*
 * Make this pipeline a nextflow 2 implementation
 */
nextflow.enable.dsl=2

...

params.samtools_total_threads = '4'
params.samtools_mem_per_thread = '8'

...
```

## Attempt 2

After Attempt 1 failed, I figured the most 'Nextflow-like way' would be to generate tuples for each combination of CPU and memory that I want to test. Unfortunately, it doesn't appear that it's possible to set CPU and memory directives using parameters passed into the `process`, but only with global variables.

I get the following `No such variable` error with the below code (note: most of this code is courtesy of @Steve):

```
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 21.04.3
Launching `02-SAMTOOLS_SORT.nf` [desperate_aryabhata] - revision: fb9e79055a
No such variable: total_threads

 -- Check script '02-SAMTOOLS_SORT.nf' at line: 33 or see '.nextflow.log' file for more details
```

**Process code**

```
process samtools_coordinate_sort_proc {

    tag { "${bam.baseName}" }

    executor='slurm'
    queue = 'normal'
    cpus = total_threads
    memory = total_mem.GB
    clusterOptions = "--time 5:00:00 --account <account>"

    /* delete files upon completion (I think) */
    cleanup = true

    input:
    path(bam)
    val(total_threads)
    val(total_mem)

    output:
    path("${bam.baseName}.csorted.bam")

    script:

    def additional_threads = task.cpus - 1

    def avail_mem = task.memory ? task.memory.toGiga().intdiv(task.cpus) : 0
    println "avail_mem: $avail_mem"
    def mem_per_thread = avail_mem ? "${avail_mem}G" : ''
    println "mem_per_thread: $mem_per_thread"

    """
    samtools sort \\
        -@ "${additional_threads}" \\
    -m ${mem_per_thread} \\
        -o "${bam.baseName}.csorted.bam" \\
    -T "${bam.baseName}.csorted" \\
        --write-index \\
        "${bam}"
    """
}
```

## Possible attempt 3

Of course, it would be *super* easy to do this with a couple of `bash` scripts, but I'm trying to do it in `Nextflow` for two reasons:

1. To learn `Nextflow` better
2. Because the traces provided by `Nextflow` are super convenient (though I could get this information from `SLURM`, too).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible to specify [dynamic computing resources](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#dynamic-computing-resources) using a closure. For example, this sets the [cpus](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#cpus) and [memory](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#memory) directives using the values supplied via the input declaration:

```
nextflow.enable.dsl=2

process test_samtools {

    echo true

    cpus { cpus }
    memory { memory }

    input:
    tuple path(bam), val(cpus), val(memory)

    script:
    def additional_threads = task.cpus - 1

    def avail_mem = task.memory ? task.memory.toGiga().intdiv(task.cpus) : 0
    def mem_per_thread = avail_mem ? "-m ${avail_mem}G" : ''

    """
    echo samtools sort \\
        -@ "${additional_threads}" \\
        ${mem_per_thread} \\
        -o "${bam.baseName}.csorted.bam" \\
        -T "${bam.baseName}.csorted" \\
        --write-index \\
        "${bam}"
    """
}

workflow {

    cpu_ch = Channel.of( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    memory_ch = Channel.of( 1.GB, 2.GB, 4.GB )

    Channel.fromPath( './data/*.bam' )
        | combine( cpu_ch )
        | combine( memory_ch )
        | test_samtools
}
```